# SQL query for finding records where members within each group are the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I am sorry for the basic question. I have a table with two columns and I would like to extract Gene with Class = M (my expected output below). I tried where Class = 'P' and Group by Gene, but still I have both Gene a and b as outputs. Can you help me please?

```
Gene    Class
a   m
a   m
a   m
b   p   
b   m
b   p
c   p
c   p   
c   p
```

This is what I expect to have..

```
Gene    Class
a   m
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Note that in the absence of a PK, you don't really have a table (in a relational sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having` if `class` always has to have the same value:

```
select gene, min(class)
from t
group by gene
having min(class) = max(class) and min(class) = 'm';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b1e306e1d1077f6525f045c87384caf4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you very much for the quick help. I tried the query and it said 'Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where min(Class) = max(Class) and min(Class) = 'm'' at line 4'. Is it because I am using MySQL server?

Comment: @nadal-t . . . No.  I typed `where` where I intended `having`.